# Converting string to double error

Tags: java, string, double

I have a problem converting a basic float array to string and then to double.

I have:

```
 private static float[] getSample() {

      float[] sample = new float[sampleSize];

      // Gets the sample an returns it
      sampleProvider.fetchSample(sample, 0);
      return sample;
  }
```

Which return a float[] then I use:

```
String sampleColor = Arrays.toString(getSample());
```

This for example returns: [0.62]. I think the problem is with the square brackets
I can verify by using:

```
System.out.println(sampleColor);
```

But when I try to convert it to double it just gives me an error. I try to convert it using parseDouble:

```
double colorT = Double.parseDouble(sampleColor);
```

Comment: What is your intent? An floatArray may contain multiple values. And you want to convert it into ONE double value??? Or do you want an double array?

Comment: I agree with Benjamin: until you explain why you are trying to treat an array of double values as if it were a single value, it won't be possible to make sense of this question.

Comment: The string will only have one value e.g [x] where x will be the value that is why I dont want array of doubles but only one double from the answers I saw that I need to remove the brackets in order to do that so my question in answered thank anyway for the time to look at it.

Comment: If you only ever need one value, then you really should modify the `getSample()` method so that it returns `float` and not `float[]`. Otherwise the method is doing more work than it needs to, and forces client code to do more work than is necessary.

Comment: Yeah I will change the code thank you for the heads - up

Comment: You can put a float value directly into a double variable. Like: double d = floatArray[0];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the [] are in the string while parsing it will throw an exception. to parse it you will have to remove them first. example:`samplecolor=sampleColor.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "");`

Comment: And what if there are multiple values in the array?

Comment: It is my mistake not to clarify that it will return only one value but the array is needed.

Comment: then you can split the string at ever `,`. now you have an array of strings with values like `0.62`, which you can easyly convert while iterating over it

Comment: If an array is being returned then it makes no sense to create a `String` only to call `split` and turn it back into an array.

Comment: i just continued the steps. i know there are other ways where you convert directly without taking the string first

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you just want the first float from the array:

```
double colorT = getSample()[0];
```

Note: There is no need to convert to String as an intermediate step.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert a float[] into a double[] you can use following code:

```
float[] fArray = new float[] {0.62f};

double[] dArray = new double[fArray.length];

for (int i = 0; i < dArray.length; i++) {
    dArray[i] = fArray[i];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You're right, it is because of the brackets.
What `Double.parseDouble(String s)` is expecting is a String containing a Double value. Here, you're giving it a String that is technically an array of Double values.

The way to solve this is for you to parse your String. For that you'll need to remove the brackets, and to separate the values by commas if there might be multiple of them in the array.

Comment: This ignores the question: why is the OP trying to treat an array of values as though it were a single value.

Comment: As much as it seems weird to me to do it that way as well, the question really is about converting a String that contains an array of values into a Double, so it doesn't really ignore the question.

Comment: But the call to `parseDouble` will fail if the array did contain multiple values, and this answer does not really address that. Also, I think it's better to try to talk someone out of using the wrong method if you think they're on the wrong track.

Comment: I absolutely agree with that! However, as for the multiple values concern, I addressed it at the end of my answer. I was editing it to add some code to it to address this situation better when an answer was accepted and mine got downvoted.